# what is this error about? ! Undefined control sequence

Tags: errors, pdftex

Could anyone fix this error?

```
\begin{center}
 $  \widehat{T}(c) = \footnotesize
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt}
\medmuskip = 0mu  \dfrac{1}{n}\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathbf{1} \rangle}+ T_{0}(c)\\\dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathb{1} \rangle}+ T_{1}(c)\\ \vdots \\\dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathb{1} \rangle} +T_{n-1}(c) \end{bmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{n}\begin{bmatrix}
           \dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathb{1} \rangle}+\psi^{-1}_{1}+...+\psi^{-1}_{n-1}\\
\dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathb{1} \rangle}+w_{n}^{-1}\psi^{-1}_{1}+...+w^{-(n-1)}_{n})\psi^{-1}_{n-1}\\
\vdots
\\
\dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathb \rangle}+w^{-(n-1)}_{n}\psi^{-1}_{1}+..+w^{-(n-1)^{2}}_{n}\psi^{-1}_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix} $
\end{center}

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \langle c,\mathb
{1} \rangle
l.238 ...)\\\dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathb{1} \rangle}
+ T_{1}(c)\\ \vdots \\\dfr...
```

Comment: Replace five instances of `\mathb` with `\mathbf`.

Comment: Undefined control sequence-errors means LaTeX encountered a control sequence/macro/command that isn't defined anywhere (class, packages, etc.). In the error message itself, the last macro on the first line, in your case `\mathb`, is the culprit. As @Mico says you probably intended `\mathbf`, which is for bold math. (The very last one though, in `\langle c,\mathb \rangle` I guess you should just remove altogether, it doesn't seem to make sense.)

Comment: Yes thanks I corrected it. but still I get the error:  `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \langle c,\mathb
{1} \rangle
l.231 \dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathb{1} \rangle}
+w_{n}^{-1}\psi^{-1}_{1}+...+w^{...`

Comment: @user9272398: ... because you're still using `\mathb` and not `\mathbf`.

Answer (score 5):

Check your input: you have `\mathb` where `\mathbf` seems to be expected and also `\mathb \rangle` where it should be `\mathbf{1}\rangle`.

The idea of reducing the size is interesting, but not implemented correctly, because `\footnotesize` doesn't really work in math mode.

Here's a better version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox{\fbmatrixbox}
\newenvironment{fbmatrix}
 {\left[\begin{lrbox}{\fbmatrixbox}\footnotesize$\displaystyle\begin{matrix}}
 {\end{matrix}$\end{lrbox}\usebox{\fbmatrixbox}\right]}

\begin{document}

\[
\widehat{T}(c) =
\frac{1}{n}\begin{fbmatrix}
  \dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathbf{1} \rangle} + T_{0}(c)
  \\[3ex]
  \dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathbf{1} \rangle}+ T_{1}(c)
  \\
  \vdots
  \\
  \dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathbf{1} \rangle} +T_{n-1}(c)
  \end{fbmatrix}=
\frac{1}{n}\begin{fbmatrix}
  \dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathbf{1} \rangle}+\psi^{-1}_{1}+\dots+\psi^{-1}_{n-1}
  \\[3ex]
  \dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathbf{1} \rangle}+w_{n}^{-1}\psi^{-1}_{1}+\dots+
  w^{-(n-1)}_{n})\psi^{-1}_{n-1}
  \\
  \vdots
  \\
  \dfrac{1}{\langle c,\mathbf{1} \rangle}+w^{-(n-1)}_{n}\psi^{-1}_{1}+\dots+
  w^{-(n-1)^{2}}_{n}\psi^{-1}_{n-1}
\end{fbmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `center` for math displays.

The idea is to set the matrix with reduced font size in a box, where we can safely issue `\footnotesize` and start math mode.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to fixing the (possibly not so obvious?) typo `\mathb`, you may want to rethink how you approach the display of the equation. The `bmatrix` environment -- like all other matrix-like environments of the `amsmath` and `mathtools` packages -- renders its contents in text style by default. This doesn't seem optimal for the use case at hand; you've tried to work around it by using `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`, but the result still looks cramped to me because of the tight line spacing.

Here's an alternative solution, which uses `aligned` environments instead of `bmatrix` environments. Note that the column contents are left-aligned, as that appears to lead to more-readable output for the equation at hand. (If you would rather center-set the column contents, simply use `gathered` environments instead of `aligned` environments and omit the `&` alignment markers.) Finally, in order make the input easier to read, I've also replaced all six instances of `\frac{1}{\langle c , \mathbf{1} \rangle}` with a macro called (rather unimaginatively) `\myfrac`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for 'aligned' and 'gathered' environments
\usepackage{mleftright} % for \mleft and \mright macros
\newcommand\myfrac{\frac{1}{\langle c , \mathbf{1} \rangle}} % occurs 6 times

\begin{document}
\[  
\widehat{T}(c) 
 =\frac{1}{n}
  \mleft[ \begin{aligned}
    &\myfrac + T_{0}(c) \\ 
    &\myfrac + T_{1}(c) \\ 
    &\quad\vdots \\
    &\myfrac + T_{n-1}(c) 
  \end{aligned} \mright]
 =\frac{1}{n}
  \mleft[ \begin{aligned}
    &\myfrac + \psi^{-1}_{1} +\dots+ \psi^{-1}_{n-1} \\ 
    &\myfrac + w_{n}^{-1}\psi^{-1}_{1} +\dots+ w^{-(n-1)}_{n}\psi^{-1}_{n-1} \\ 
    &\quad\vdots \\ 
    &\myfrac + w^{-(n-1)}_{n}\psi^{-1}_{1} +\dots+ w^{-(n-1)^{2}}_{n}\psi^{-1}_{n-1}
  \end{aligned} \mright] 
\]
\end{document}
```